# Avoiding a full re-initialization when making changes to transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

When I use the GUI to make any changes to transactional replication on SQL server, I live in fear of the "the changes you have made require a reinitialization of all articles" dialog.

I have had this happen even when doing something simple like adding or removing individual tables.

How do I avoid this?

Are there replication *settings* that impact when a full reinitialization is required? I found [this blog post](http://kevine323.blogspot.com/2011/03/adding-table-article-to-transactional.html) that claims that publication properties @immediate_sync and @allow_anonymous should be set to 0, I've done that but I've still sometimes had it prompt to reinitialize the whole thing.

Should I be scripting the add/remove instead of using the GUI?

Also, we frequently remove a table from replication but need to add it back in later, are there scripts out there to preserve the replication settings so this process is easier?

Comment: Still doesn't entirely answer the question of WHY?, but I found a similar post here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57630/157

Answer (score 1):

> I've done that but I've still sometimes had it prompt to reinitialize the whole thing.

The snapshot will **only contain the new table** that has been added.

> Also, we frequently remove a table from replication but need to add it back in later, are there scripts out there to preserve the replication settings so this process is easier?

Script out replication - right click - script to file. Change the parameters `@immediate_sync` and `@allow_anonymous` should be set to `0`.

Run the script post completion of your work.

Also, check my answer for [Transactional replication altering tables and adding stored procedures](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45444/8783) that will help when you are adding columns to existing replication.