# Automatically add new dbo objects in SQL Publication

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

Is it possible to automatically add new dbo objects to SQL transactional replication? Is there some out of the box solution for that or that can be achieved by T-SQL? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was kinda intruiged by your question, since we use transactional replication a lot. So I tried to come with a script to answer your question (run inside the publication db):

```
-- your publication name
DECLARE @PubName SYSNAME = 'publication name'

-- your subscriber
DECLARE @subscriber SYSNAME = 'target server name'
DECLARE @subscriberDatabase SYSNAME = 'target db name'

 -- Get publication id 
DECLARE @PubId INT
SELECT @PubId = pubid
FROM   syspublications
WHERE  name = @PubName 

-- Find tables in dbo schema, not in current publication
DECLARE tablecursor CURSOR fast_forward FOR
  SELECT TOP(2) o.name  -- for testing I used a TOP clause
  FROM   sys.objects o
  WHERE  type = 'U'
         AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')
         AND object_id NOT IN (
            SELECT objid
            FROM   sysarticles
            WHERE  pubid = @PubId
         )

DECLARE @tablename AS sysname

OPEN tablecursor

FETCH next FROM tablecursor INTO @tablename

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    -- Adding the transactional article
    EXEC sp_addarticle 
            @publication = @PubName
        ,@article = @tablename
        ,@source_owner = N'dbo'
        ,@source_object = @tablename
        ,@type = N'logbased'
        ,@schema_option = 0x08030F3--0x80030F3
        ,@vertical_partition = N'true'
    -- All columns
    EXEC sp_articlecolumn 
        @publication = @PubName, 
        @article = @tablename;


    FETCH next FROM tablecursor INTO @tablename
END

CLOSE tablecursor

DEALLOCATE tablecursor  

EXEC sp_dropsubscription 
  @publication = @PubName, 
  @article = N'all',
  @subscriber = @subscriber;

exec sp_addsubscription 
     @publication = @PubName
    ,@subscriber = @subscriber
    ,@destination_db = @subscriberDatabase
    ,@subscription_type = N'Push'
    ,@sync_type = N'automatic'
    ,@article = N'ALL', @update_mode = N'read only'
    ,@subscriber_type = 0

exec sp_addpushsubscription_agent 
    @publication = @PubName
    ,@subscriber = @subscriber
    ,@subscriber_db = @subscriberDatabase
    ,@job_login = null
    ,@job_password = null
    ,@subscriber_security_mode = 0
    ,@subscriber_login = N'some login'
    ,@subscriber_password = 'some (matching:)) password'
    ,@frequency_type = 64
    ,@frequency_interval = 1
    ,@frequency_relative_interval = 1
    ,@frequency_recurrence_factor = 0
    ,@frequency_subday = 4
    ,@frequency_subday_interval = 5
    ,@active_start_time_of_day = 0
    ,@active_end_time_of_day = 235959
    ,@active_start_date = 0
    ,@active_end_date = 0
    ,@dts_package_location = N'Distributor'

-- Re init subscription(s)
--EXEC sp_reinitsubscription 
--   @publication = @PubName
--  ,@subscriber =  @subscriber
--  ,@invalidate_snapshot = 1

-- Start snapshot agent
EXEC sp_startpublication_snapshot @publication = @PubName
```

Now I found out the hard way, there are some things that can go wrong:

- First of all, its obvious to restart the snapshot agent to pick up new articles. However, on my test machine the snapshot agent didn't pick up newly added articles. I did some googling and found simular issues ([Snapshot not picking up new articles in SQL Server 2012 transaction replication when added through script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33028/snapshot-not-picking-up-new-articles-in-sql-server-2012-transaction-replication)). I ended up with dropping and re adding the subscription.
- The @schema_option parameter for sp_addarticle is a bit of obscure to me. I used some tables that had timestamp columns and these were propagated to the subscriber as BINARY(8) and the rows could not be inserted at the subscriber ("Field Size too large"). See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b56433c1-7f6f-4d2c-9593-3a11035fb1fe/cannot-update-a-timestamp-column-on-subscriber-using-transactional-replication?forum=sqlreplication and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addarticle-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Many thanks to your response, it gave me a few ideas that I will try. 
For us is also very important not to snapshot each table again. Will update the post after my shots.